# How to create a database and a table in python

Tags: python, dolphindb

How to create a database and a table in python

I create a DFS table in DolphinDB GUI. The partition type is COMPO, the code is:

```
dbName="dfs://forwardtekDdb1"
tableName="windTurbine"
login("admin","123456")
if(exists(dbName))
    dropDatabase(dbName)
    
tableSchema = table(100:0,`id`tm`val,[INT,DATETIME,FLOAT]);
db1 = database("",VALUE,2017.01M..2020.12M)
db2 = database("",RANGE,0..1000*30+1)
db = database(dbName,COMPO,[db1,db2])
dfsTable = db.createPartitionedTable(tableSchema,tableName,`tm`id)
```

How to copy them to python? I only find an example about creating DFS table in VALUE partition. I don't konw how to create a DFS table in COMPO partition.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link!
https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3/blob/a51181b891c8abf7b01ceda777e1449f9524a095/test/test_database.py#L370